# How to cite the same reference in a paragraph twice in APA style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

**Content in the paper:**

> This problem can be solved with the application of machine learning
>   algorithms. Machine Learning is the process of programming computers
>   to optimize a performance criterion using example data or past
>   experience (Alpaydin, 2010). .......[some of my own content] A
>   learning routing program is able to adapt to the best path by
>   monitoring the network traffic (Alpaydin, 2010).

At the beginning of the paragraph, I have cited the author and then I have some content which are compiled by me. Then I am again using an example given by the author which needs to be cited. So, I have cited him again at the end of the paragraph. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check out an example [from the invaluable APA Style Blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/04/when-to-include-the-year-in-citations-appearing-more-than-once-in-a-paragraph.html):

> Morin (1988) described two separate but linked epidemics. . . . Morin
>   distinguished the HIV (viral) epidemic from the subsequent AIDS
>   (disease) epidemic, foreseeing the ultimate convergence of preventing
>   the spread of the virus and managing the disease it causes. . . .
>   Morin also discussed a third epidemic . . . . This third epidemic is
>   as much a part of the pathology of AIDS as the virus itself (Morin,
>   1988).
>
> Socioeconomic status (SES) and chronic diseases rather consistently
>   fall on a gradient, where those of relatively lower SES have poorer
>   health and are more often afflicted by multiple diseases than those
>   above them on the SES ladder (Adler & Stewart, 2010). . . . Adler and
>   Stewart (2010) offered a framework to explain the major pathways by
>   which SES can influence health outcomes. . . . The model is
>   developmental, illustrating individual, social, and structural
>   influences on disease over the lifespan (Adler & Stewart, 2010).